# Auxiliary functions when defining instances in Haskell, how to group?

Tags: haskell

```
instance Num Polinom where
    let
        zmnoziKoef :: [Rational] -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
        zmnoziKoef _ [] = []
        zmnoziKoef [] _ = []
        zmnoziKoef (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x * y) : pomnoziKoef x ys `sestejKoef` (xs `zmnoziKoef` (y:ys))
        sestejKoef :: [Rational] -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
        sestejKoef xs [] = xs
        sestejKoef [] ys = ys
        sestejKoef (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x + y):(sestejKoef xs ys)
        pomnoziKoef :: Rational -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
        pomnoziKoef a = map (a *) 

    negate (Polinom koef) = Polinom $ pomnoziKoef (-1) koef
    (Polinom koef1) + (Polinom koef2) = Polinom $ sestejKoef koef1 koef2
    (Polinom koef1) * (Polinom koef2) = Polinom $ zmnoziKoef koef1 koef2
    fromInteger x = Polinom $ [fromInteger x]
```

So this code works, but is there a way to make a group of auxiliary functions, so that I don't have to write them after every definition.

Like this:

```
instance Num Polinom where
    negate (Polinom koef) = Polinom $ pomnoziKoef (-1) koef
    (Polinom koef1) + (Polinom koef2) = Polinom $ sestejKoef koef1 koef2
    (Polinom koef1) * (Polinom koef2) = Polinom $ zmnoziKoef koef1 koef2
    fromInteger x = Polinom $ [fromInteger x]
        where
            zmnoziKoef :: [Rational] -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
            zmnoziKoef _ [] = []
            zmnoziKoef [] _ = []
            zmnoziKoef (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x * y) : pomnoziKoef x ys `sestejKoef` (xs `zmnoziKoef` (y:ys))

            sestejKoef :: [Rational] -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
            sestejKoef xs [] = xs
            sestejKoef [] ys = ys

            sestejKoef (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x + y):(sestejKoef xs ys)

            pomnoziKoef :: Rational -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
            pomnoziKoef a = map (a *)
```

Comment: Put them at the top level. Every `let` and `where` must be associated with precisely one declaration - there is no way to "share" a `let` among all the declarations in a class, or among any declarations at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `let` and `where` can only be used in one expression or declaration by design. If you want to use them as auxiliary functions for more than one declaration simply put them at top level:

```
zmnoziKoef :: [Rational] -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
zmnoziKoef _ [] = []
zmnoziKoef [] _ = []
zmnoziKoef (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x * y) : pomnoziKoef x ys `sestejKoef` (xs `zmnoziKoef` (y:ys))

sestejKoef :: [Rational] -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
sestejKoef xs [] = xs
sestejKoef [] ys = ys

sestejKoef (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x + y):(sestejKoef xs ys)

pomnoziKoef :: Rational -> [Rational] -> [Rational]
pomnoziKoef a = map (a *) 

instance Num Polinom where
    negate (Polinom koef) = Polinom $ pomnoziKoef (-1) koef
    (Polinom koef1) + (Polinom koef2) = Polinom $ sestejKoef koef1 koef2
    (Polinom koef1) * (Polinom koef2) = Polinom $ zmnoziKoef koef1 koef2
    fromInteger x = Polinom $ [fromInteger x]
```

If you want this to be kept private to the module you can simply avoid exporting them by using an export list:

```
module MyModule(funcA, funcB, funcC) where
...
```

In the above code only `funcA`, `funcB` and `funcC` will be exported when importing the module (plus all instances).